# How we can get forest name and data directory in MarkLogic using Xquery

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I am trying to get the list of forests and its data directory in a particular host/node can anyone help me with a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the list of forests from the [`xdmp:host-status()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:host-status), look for the `h:assignment` that have the specified `h:host-id`, and then use the `forest-id` of each forest to fetch the [`xdmp:forest-status()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:forest-status) to obtain the `data-dir` for each forest.

```
declare namespace h = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/host";
declare namespace f = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/status/forest";

let $host := xdmp:host()
for $forest-id in xdmp:host-status($host)/h:assignments/h:assignment[h:host-id = $host]/h:forest-id/data() 
return 
  <f:forest>{ 
      xdmp:forest-status($forest-id)/(f:forest-name, f:data-dir) 
  }</f:forest>
```

Comment: This query returns all forests in the cluster, Even if I pass the hostname in xdmp:host-status(xdmp:host(xxxxxxx)) but I want particular host details only.

Comment: whoops! Forgot to add the predicate (was testing on a single-node cluster :) ). I've updated to correct that.